# Does oracle store transaction date of data?

Tags: oracle, date, logging, oracle11g, transactions

Im currently using oracle 11g. I had extracted data from the schema once at a specific date to do some cleansing process. Suppose that now i would want to extract again but only with new/updated data from the last date i extracted, is there anyway i could get it? unfortunately these data does not have any column that store last edited date.

i was wondering if Oracle would automatically store that type of info that i could check? perhaps any transaction log?

Thanks,

A Physal

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to enable flashback and then you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
MINUS
SELECT * FROM table1 AS OF TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000';
```

To get all the rows changed since `2018-01-01`.